# What is the easiest way to mass-transfer (via USB-C) hundreds of files (like my DCIM folder) from one smartphone to another smartphone or external HD?

Tags: applications

A lot of the standard Android file transfer apps only allow manual selection - aka they don't easily allow me to do "select all" of hundreds of files.

Interested in both transferring to a 1TB SSD hard drive or to another smartphone.

Prefer to not go through a PC because of friction/lag/sudden disconnects.

Also how can I even view files from one phone onto the other phone?

Comment: You should clarify if having a PC is acceptable or not.

Comment: Plus what OS the PC runs, if there's one.

Comment: The definition of "easy" may vary for persons and situations. But hundreds of pictures, if not thousands, is not a big amount of data. Connect to a Wi-Fi network. Install MiXplorer or a similar app on both sides. Run FTP server on one side. Copy and paste on the other side.